# Eloquent query builder whereDate throwing error: Unknown column '2017-05-03 12:00:00' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Can anyone tell me whhat's wrong with this query?

```
$orderdaytimes = OrderDayTime::whereColumn([
                    ['date','>=',$start],
                    ['date','<=',$end]
                 ]) -> get();
```

it's giving me the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2017-05-03 12:00:00' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `order_day_times` where (`date` >= `2017-05-03 12:00:00` and `date` <= `2017-05-31 12:00:00`))

I've tested it in DB directly and the following works:

```
select * from `order_day_times` where (`date` >= '2017-05-03 12:00:00' and `date` <= '2017-05-31 12:00:00')
```

But eloquent automatically add "`" to queries? T_T

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your table have a column called `Column` ?

Comment: no it doesn't. this query works if i replace the quotation marks as described in the question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `whereColumn` by `where`:

```
$orderdaytimes = OrderDayTime::where([
    ['date','>=',$start],
    ['date','<=',$end]
]) -> get();
```

The `whereColumn` method may be used to verify that two columns are equal. The `where` method just add a `WHERE` clause to your query and that's what you want.

Last paragraph of https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses:

> You may also pass an array of conditions to the where function:
>
> $users = DB::table('users')->where([
>          ['status', '=', '1'],
>          ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
>      ])->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use between operator like below I have use

```
 $orderdaytimes = OrderDayTime::whereRaw("(date>='$start_date' and  
 date<='$end_date'))");
```

I hope this will helpful to you. I have used whereRaw

Comment: It has some security issues!